# Iterating though array is finding no values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a small script for a client meant to create numerology results for an input name. After my first iteration through the name and its corresponding values, I then need to add the digits in the final result, and get what's called a "MASTER NUMBER." The problem I'm having is iterating through the final result, which keeps returning 0 - Checking along the iteration shows me that it's not finding values in the array.  Where have I gone wrong?

```
<?php
if($_POST) 
 {
     // create an array based on chaldean numerology

     $ar = array('A' => 1,
         'B' => 2,'C' => 3,'D' => 4,'E' => 5,'F' => 6,'G' => 7,'H' => 8,'I' => 9,
         'J' => 1,'K' => 2,'L' => 3,'M' => 4,'N' => 5,'O' => 6,'P' => 7,'Q' => 8,
         'R' => 9,'S' => 1,'T' => 2,'U' => 3,'V' => 4,'W' => 5,'X' => 6,'Y' => 7,
         'Z' => 8,'1' => 1,'2' => 2,'3' => 3,'4' => 4,'5' => 5,'6' => 6,'7' => 7,
         '8' => 8,'9' => 9);

     //get the value entered by post method
     $fname = $_POST['fname'];
     //make it upper case. to avoid messing with small letters.
     $fname = strtoupper($fname);
     //find the length of the string entered
     $len = strlen($fname);

     //set a temp value to calculate
     $fullnum = 0;
     $masternum = 0;

     //now loop through the string one by one and add the values
     for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++)
     {
         $alpha  = $fname[$i];
         $fullnum = $ar[$alpha] + $fullnum;
     }


     //now loop through the fullnum one by one and add the values
     $flen = strlen($fullnum);

     for($i=0; $i<$flen; $i++)
     {
         $alpha  = $fullnum[$i];
         $masternum = $ar[$alpha] + $masternum;
     }

     //print the result
     //echo "FLEN = " . $flen . "<br>";
     echo "<hr>INTEGRATED SELF NUMBER: ". $fullnum . "/" . $masternum;
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="fname"  value="Full Name" />
     <input type="submit" value="calculate" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is frightening... I left some comment to this question some days ago. Now I come back and I see that comment is gone. I did not receive any notification about the comment being removed or anything. What happened? Where is that comment?

Comment: There actually were 6 comments to this question from three users. Apparently they _all_ got removed. That leaves a _very_ bad feeling in my stomach. Such form of censorship should not get introduced here on SO. _Especially_ not without leaving any trace.

Comment: I only actually ever saw one comment - that IS disturbing...

Comment: There were two replies to my original comment, which indeed was teasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in that "algorithm": 1. you did not define the key "0" in that dictionary array and 2. you have to convert the numeric type of $fullnum into a string to be able to access a character inside in array notation as you try to.

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    // create an array based on chaldean numerology    
    $ar = [
        'A' => 1,
        'B' => 2,'C' => 3,'D' => 4,'E' => 5,'F' => 6,'G' => 7,'H' => 8,'I' => 9,
        'J' => 1,'K' => 2,'L' => 3,'M' => 4,'N' => 5,'O' => 6,'P' => 7,'Q' => 8,
        'R' => 9,'S' => 1,'T' => 2,'U' => 3,'V' => 4,'W' => 5,'X' => 6,'Y' => 7,
        'Z' => 8,'0' => 0,'1' => 1,'2' => 2,'3' => 3,'4' => 4,'5' => 5,'6' => 6,
        '7' => 7,'8' => 8,'9' => 9
    ];

    //get the value entered by post method
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    //make it upper case. to avoid messing with small letters.
    $fname = strtoupper($fname);
    //find the length of the string entered
    $len = strlen($fname);

    //set a temp value to calculate
    $fullnum = 0;
    $masternum = 0;

    //now loop through the string one by one and add the values
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        $alpha  = $fname[$i];
        $fullnum = $ar[$alpha] + $fullnum;
    }

    //now loop through the fullnum one by one and add the values
    $fullnum = "$fullnum";
    $flen = strlen($fullnum);
    for($i=0; $i<$flen; $i++) {
        $alpha  = $fullnum[$i];
        $masternum = $ar[$alpha] + $masternum;
    }

    //print the result
    //echo "FLEN = " . $flen . "<br>";
    echo "<hr>INTEGRATED SELF NUMBER: ". $fullnum . "/" . $masternum;
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname"  value="Full Name" />
<input type="submit" value="calculate" />
</form>
```

That slightly modified version *does* create an output. However I certainly do not know if that is the correct mystical number, since I had to alter the magic dictionary and add an obviously missing value (the "0"), since the "algorithm" cannot work without, for obvious reasons. Sorry for that. But I suspect that does not really matter, does it? ;-)

Comment: That totally did it - looks like the biggest culprit was the fact that my variable was cast as an integer, rather than a string.  Thanks - stupid mistake on my part.